# Charge a supercapacitor in 4-20 mA circuit

Tags: supercapacitor

I want to design a charger circuit in my project.

At first I have an IC (AD694) to produce 4-20 mA current, then must charge one 100F, 2.7V supercap.

How can do it?

I want to use a breadboard for this circuit.

I know some ICs such LTC3326 and some LTM can be used. But I want ICs I can use on breadboard.

Maybe some one can offer other way.

Comment: Please use space after each comma and period. As long as you limit the compliance voltage to 2.7 V or less, you should have everything you need. Draw a schematic and we’ll take a look at it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? how much load is on the supercap?

Comment: I want use this supercapacitor as power supply to operate a sensor wich need  200ma input current.I shude charge and discharge the supercap fast as possible.

Comment: Why not make your sensor 3-wire instead?

Comment: I have to use one 12V DC power supply at first.
After than 4-20mA I shuld charge and discharge the supercap in about 8 minutes.
Because I want discharge it in to the sensor wich need 200mA to operate. I should work with 4-20mA ,this is my first part of project.

Comment: I assume the sensor will act periodically. How much time does one sensor activity need and what pause time is acceptable? In other words: What is the average energy needed over time compared to the available energy.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, it is simple. You connect your 4-20 to the supercap with the correct polarity, and then the circuit will drive a constant current in to charge it. BUT it will raise the voltage to whatever is necessary to drive that current, which will almost certainly be greater than 2V7, and will damage the supercap. So, protect it with a zener across the terminals so voltage cannot exceed 2V7. BTW, shorting out a 4-20 current loop will not damage it.

Comment: After than AD694 we have 10 volt constant output and I have to limit this voltage to charge 2.7 V super capacitor.charging time is important for me

Comment: @isa.b You are using constant current, so the time to charge to 2V7 does not depend on your maximum output voltage. You can only dump a maximum of 20mA into it, irrespective of voltage.

Comment: BTW, using 20mA to charge a 100F capacitor to 1 Volt will take more than 1 hour, so to fully charge it from a 20mA source to 2V7 will take almost 3 hours

Comment: Tanks for your guide.but 3hour is very long time.isn't any way to chrge it fast?if the current be 4ma what I can do?! :O

Comment: If you only have 20mA or less to charge the capacitor there is nothing you can do to make it faster. You need an external power supply such as a solar cell or small wind turbine

Comment: This mean I can't use boost converter or other circuit  to charge faster?!

Comment: @isa.b Yes, providing you have the voltage. But you say you only have 10V, so at best it would reduce charging time to about an hour.

Comment: I have to use one 12V DC power supply at first then I can't use solar cell!
After than 4-20mA I shude charge and discharge the supercap in minute.
Because I want discharge it in to the sensor wich need 200mA to operate.
Can you help me??